# Trying to hide span when inputs have a GCD of 1 (Code included)

Tags: javascript, function, variables

I have a function that's supposed to carry out 2 tasks:

1) Simplify 2 numbers by pulling out the GCD (this feature works)

2) Hide a span if the numbers cannot be simplified (does not work)

I included the code below, but this JsFiddle best illustrates what I mean: http://jsfiddle.net/vmfL5rzy/

JAVASCRIPT

```
$(document).ready(function () {

function reduce(numerator,denominator){
    $this = $(this);
  var gcd = function gcd(a,b){
    return b ? gcd(b, a%b) : a;
  };
  gcd = gcd(numerator,denominator);
  if ((denominator/gcd) == 1) {
  return [numerator/gcd];
  } else {
if(gcd === 1){
  $(this).parent(".SimplificationPrompt").hide(); //THIS IS THE PART THAT'S WRONG 
return [numerator/gcd +"|"+ denominator/gcd];
}else{
return [numerator/gcd +"|"+ denominator/gcd];
}

  }
}


var reducefraction = reduce(4,12); 
    $('.reducefraction').html(reducefraction );

var reducefraction2 = reduce(1,5);
    $('.reducefraction2').html(reducefraction2 );

    });
```

HTML

```
<b>This should be hidden</b>: <span class="SimplificationPrompt"><span class="reducefraction"></span></span>
<br>
This shouldn't be hidden: <span class="SimplificationPrompt"><span class="reducefraction2"></span></span>
```

Comment: You should check what `this` is in your `reduce` function it's not what you think it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were trying to get the element by using `$(this)` inside a function which is wrong

What you need to do is send the elem as a parameter to the function and then use it.

See code snippet

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  function reduce(numerator, denominator, elem) {

    var gcd = function gcd(a, b) {
      return b ? gcd(b, a % b) : a;
    };
    gcd = gcd(numerator, denominator);
    if ((denominator / gcd) == 1) {
      return [numerator / gcd];
    } else {
      if (gcd === 1) {

        return [numerator / gcd + "|" + denominator / gcd];
      } else {
        elem.parent().hide();
        return [numerator / gcd + "|" + denominator / gcd];
      }

    }
  }


  var reducefraction = reduce(4, 12, $('.reducefraction'));
  $('.reducefraction').html(reducefraction);

  var reducefraction2 = reduce(1, 5, $('.reducefraction2'));
  $('.reducefraction2').html(reducefraction2);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<b>This should be hidden</b>: <span class="SimplificationPrompt"><span class="reducefraction"></span></span>
<br> This shouldn't be hidden: <span class="SimplificationPrompt"><span class="reducefraction2"></span></span>
```